# Resize divs related to parent divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 4 divs. I want to change the size of the inner divs compared to parent divs.
I want to dynamically change the child div size related to parent's one.
Now I've added .top class, but I don't really know if its needed or if it will be useful.

Here is the fiddle I'm testing with
http://jsfiddle.net/y3597/171/

jQuery below

```
$(".top").each(function () {
    $('.object').width($(".inner").parent().width());
});
```

CSS below:

```
.container1 { width: 200px; background: red; padding: 2px; }
.container2 { width: 225px; background: purple; padding: 2px; }
.container3 { width: 250px; background: blue; padding: 2px; }
.container4 { width: 275px; background: black; padding: 2px; }

/* top ? */

.inner { width: 150px; background: gray; }
.object { width: 100px; background: green; }
```

HTML below:

```
<div class="container1 top">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="object">Text 1</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container2 top">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="object">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container3 top">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="object">Text 3</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container4 top">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="object">Text 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: U can express the positions and sizes in percentage.

Comment: *"Basically I want to fill the parent divs with "green" "* - why can't you just give it `background-color:green` directly?? which exactly is the "parent divs" you're refering to?

Comment: @TJ container1 to container4. This is just example actually. I can't just set background to green. It has to dynamically change with parent's size.

Comment: @mtashev well you said *"Basically I want to fill the parent divs with "green" "* in question. Now you're saying something else... please update the question ppoperly. looks like it's a simple fix anyway.

Comment: If you simply say "i want to set the width of elements with this class to it's parent with this class"... it'll be way more understandable than the current description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to achieve this:

```
$(".top").each(function () {
    $(this).find(".object").width($(this).width()); 
});
```

In your code jQuery will check for every element with .object class in DOM on each loop. When you use (this) you are refering to element that is currently "selected" in loop.

Better way to achive this is to set widths od children to 100%, so they will inherit the witdhs from parents.